# Extract multiple lines from .txt file with sed or awk using a second .txt file with the line numbers to be extracted

Tags: awk, sed

I am trying to extract multiple lines from a raw_data.txt file having 200x10E6 lines.
The line numbers to be extract (>5000) are listed in a second .txt named lines.txt
(one line number per row).

Based on what I found out here, I tried two approaches with awk and sed:

```
awk 'NR == FNR {nums[$1]; next} FNR in nums' lines.txt raw_data.txt > selected_data.txt
```

and

```
sed ’s/$/p/‘ lines.txt | sed -n -f - raw_data.txt > selected_data.txt
```

In both cases, the selected_data.txt file was empty. I am assuming that the large number of lines to be selected and the very large number of lines in raw_data.txt are preventing the correct execution since both commands work when I selected very few lines only (<5).

Any idea to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Please, post some sample data with the related expected output for testing.
Don't post them as comments, images, tables or links to off-site
services but use text and include them to your original question. Thanks.

Comment: This issue can arise if the `\n` sequence is not what `awk` or `sed` expect. Please provide more detail on the file. Likely the `lines.txt` file is not OK. If you are on Unix, use `file your_file` and it will state if the line ending are not the same as your platform. You can also try `cat -e your_file` depending on your platform again.

Comment: most likely there is a formatting problem in your lines.txt file and when you create a test version it's correct.  To verify just extract the samples from your file `head lines.txt > sample.txt` and used that instead.

Comment: In your code `’s/$/p/‘`, those are "smart quotes" around the script, replace them with normal quotes, `'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have these two files:

```
cat lines
1
5
6
12

cat file.txt
line 1
line 2
line 3
...
line 23
line 24
line 25
```

You can read `lines` first then use that to decide what line to print in `file.txt` like so:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{line[$1]; next} 
FNR in line' lines file.txt
line 1
line 5
line 6
line 12
```

---

The reason this might not be working on *your* computer is often the line endings are not what `awk` expects.

Try this:

```
awk '{printf("%s: %s\n", FNR, $1)}' lines
1: 1
2: 5
3: 6
4: 12
```

You can also use the Unix `file` utility which will show one of:

```
file file.txt
file.txt: ASCII text
```

Or:

```
file file.txt
file.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

If your awk is expecting `\r\n` and only gets `\n` that may be your issue.

Use `dos2unix` or `unix2dos` to fix that. Or set the appropriate `RS=<what ever your line endings are>` in awk. If you have GNU awk, you can do `RS="\r?\n"` and it will work with both DOS and Unix line endings.

Comment: A comment to all contributors: Thank you for your help. The first "awk" solution suggested by dawg worked well. Importantly, the initial comment from dawg again about the format of the line number file (line terminators) was the right hypothesis. The line number file was built with copy/paste from Excel and the line terminators were exclusively CR. I changed them to LF line terminators with the following command: tr '\r' '\n' < lines.txt > lines_unix.txt and it worked smoothly. Thanks again for your time. Vey much appreciated to learn with you. Best regards.